# Steps to send message to all numbers in our database in magento backend

Tags: customer, messages

Would like to send informational message to all customers of our store. Kindly suggest how do I do that ?

Comment: may be you need some extension , we are using [this](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mage-sms-sms-notification-sms-marketing-1.html) for local customers, but this will work for international too.....

Comment: also you need to pay charges per sms....

Answer (score 0):

you can try this extension : https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mage-sms-sms-notification-sms-marketing-1.html , but you need to pay charges per sms :

```
class Topefekt_Magesms_ApiController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
    public function indexAction() {
        if (!Mage::getStoreConfig('magesms/api/active') || !Mage::getStoreConfig('magesms/api/apikey'))
            die('DISABLED');
        $params = $this->getRequest();
        $auth = $params->getParam('key') == Mage::getStoreConfig('magesms/api/apikey') ? true : false;
        $to = $params->getParam('to');
        $text = $params->getParam('text');
        $unicode = $params->getParam('unicode') ? true : false;

        if ($auth && $to && $text) {
            $sms = Mage::getModel('magesms/sms');
            $sms->setRecipient($to)
                ->setMessage($text)
                ->setType(Topefekt_Magesms_Model_Sms::TYPE_SIMPLE)  // simple sms
                ->setUnicode($unicode)
                ->send();
            if ($sms->isError())
                echo "SMSSTATUS:ERROR";
            else
                echo "SMSSTATUS:OK";
        } else {
            echo "SMSSTATUS:ERROR";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, we are using this extension but when I am clicking SMS MARKETING the following is coming. Kindly suggest : Customers found: 45255

Fatal error: Call to a member function addItem() on a non-object in /var/www/html/app/code/community/Topefekt/Magesms/Block/Marketing/Customer.php on line 16

Comment: @Gauri looks like you done something wrong at the time of installation, reinstall the extension once in demo  site and than try in live site or try contacting them, they will give good support : `bilkova@topefekt.com  , sales@topefekt.com , 
support@topefekt.com`